# delay implementation in scala

Tags: scala, stream, delay

I have implemented the following cons_stream function in scala that does not work and I am not sure why.

```
def cons_stream[T, U](x : T, y : U) = 
{
  def delay = () => y
  /// Delay takes no parameters but returns y
  (f : String ) => 
    {

      if ( f == "x") x
      else if( f == "y") delay
      else throw new Error("Invalid string use x or y")
    }
}
```

The corresponding car and cdr functions are:

```
def stream_car[T](f : String => T) : T = f("x")
def stream_cdr[T](f : String => Any)  : T = force(f("y").asInstanceOf[() => T])
```

Now I have the definition of a stream integers starting with 1

```
def integers_starting_from_n[T, U](n : Int) : String => Any =
{
      cons_stream(n, integers_starting_from_n(n+1))
}
```

Unfortunately when I try to access the stream using either stream_car or stream_cdr I get a stack overflow:

def integers = integers_starting_from_n(1)

stream_car(integers)

I have no idea why. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the stack is full of `integers_starting_from_n`. Correct? That function is recursive and is called before `cons_stream` can be executed, because it takes value of `integers_starting_from_n(n+1)` as a paremeter.

Answer (score 0):

In order to define a stream, you can use a call-by-name parameter by prepending `=>` to the type. For your example, use call-by-name with `y`.

```
def cons_stream[T, U](x:T, y: => U)
```

Comment: That seemed to get rid of the recursion but the stream_cdr throws a class cast exception. I will investigate that. Thank you.